# How could I rewrite this switch statement so an array of strings is sorted in a specific manner

Tags: swift, swift3

How could I rewrite this code so that an array of strings is sorted in the following manner: First, strings with search term as prefix. Second, strings that simply contain the search term. Lastly, everything else sorted alphabetically.

```
stringArray = stringArray.sorted(by: {
    switch ($0.hasPrefix(searchTerm), $1.hasPrefix(searchTerm) {
    case (true, true): return $0 < $1 ;
    case (true, false): return true ;
    case (false, true): return false ;
    case (false, false): return $0 < $1 
}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to change the last case of the switch statement, since you only want to change the ordering if neither the current, nor the next element starts with the searchTerm, otherwise you still prefer the element starting with the searchTerm over anything else.

Inside the case where neither of the two elements has the prefix, you check if any of them contains the searchTerm or not and you process the results in the exact same way as you did before.

```
stringArray = stringArray.sorted(by: {
    switch ($0.hasPrefix(searchTerm), $1.hasPrefix(searchTerm)){
    case (true, true): return $0 < $1
    case (true, false): return true
    case (false, true): return false
    case (false, false):
        switch ($0.contains(searchTerm), $1.contains(searchTerm)) {
        case (true, true): return $0 < $1
        case (true, false): return true
        case (false, true): return false
        case (false, false): return $0 < $1
        }
}})
```

This code has been tested in a playground and is working as expected. Using the following test cases:

```
let stringArray = ["b","ba","c","d","da","ae","aa","fae","a"]
let searchTerm = "a"
```

The result is: `["a", "aa", "ae", "ba", "da", "fae", "b", "c", "d"]`

Answer (score 1):

How about some value bindings, where clauses and wildcard patterns?

```
var stringArray = ["b","ba","c","d","da","ae","aa","fae","a"]
let searchTerm = "a"

stringArray = stringArray.sorted(by: {
    switch ($0.hasPrefix(searchTerm), $1.hasPrefix(searchTerm)){
    case (true, true): return $0 < $1
    case (false, false):
        switch ($0.contains(searchTerm), $1.contains(searchTerm)) {
        case (let x, let y) where x == y: return $0 < $1
        case (let x, _): return x
        }
    case (let x, _): return x
}})

print(stringArray.description)
```